# Show that Dynamic Time Warping is no metric

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-writing

I have been told that DTW distance does not hold the triangular inequality, but I haven't found a proof or example if that fact. How can this be shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example: Consider the three sequences $x:=[0,1,1,2]$, $y:=[0,1,2]$, $z:=[0,2,2]$. Calculate the DTW distance between any two of these sequences, using the Euclidean distance $d(a,b)=|a-b|$ between the symbols $0,1,2$. Check that: $$\operatorname{DTW}(x,z)=2, \qquad\operatorname{DTW}(x,y)=0,\qquad\operatorname{DTW}(y,z)=1.$$  Therefore the triangle inequality does not hold for $\operatorname{DTW}$, since it is not true that $$\operatorname{DTW}(x,z)\le \operatorname{DTW}(x,y) + \operatorname{DTW}(y,z).$$

Here is R code to perform this analysis:

```
> library(dtw)
> x = c(0,1,1,2)
> y = c(0,1,2)
> z = c(0,2,2)

> xz = dtw(x,z,keep=T)     # by default, dist.method="Euclidean"
> xz$distance
[1] 2
> xz$localCostMatrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    2    2
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1
[4,]    2    0    0

> xy = dtw(x,y,keep=T)
> xy$distance
[1] 0
> xy$localCostMatrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    2
[2,]    1    0    1
[3,]    1    0    1
[4,]    2    1    0

> yz = dtw(y,z,keep=T)
> yz$distance
[1] 1
> yz$localCostMatrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    2    2
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    2    0    0
```

Comment: Do you have an idea or know material, how to tweak the DTW definition in order to receive a metric?